# How to preserve format while pasting in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a switch case in a section of my function, and I need to reorder some of the cases for better code reading.

So the code at the moment looks something like this:

```
switch(parameter) {
      case "foo" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
      case "bar" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }  
      ....
      case "alpha" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
      case "beta" :  {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
 }
```

So I have hundreads of cases inside this switch statement and I need to reorder most of them. And while reordering, for example if I want to put case foo and case bar below cases alpha and beta. A simple `Ctrl+c` and `Ctrl+v` gives me an output like this:

```
switch(parameter) {
      case "alpha" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
      case "beta" :  {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
      ......
      case "foo" : {DoSomething; 
                    DoSomething; 
                    DoSomething; 
                    DoSomething; 
                    break }
      case "bar" : {DoSomething;
                    DoSomething; 
                    DoSomething;
                    DoSomething; 
                    break }  
 }
```

Rearranging this text multiple times is a cumbersome task. Is there a way a can duplicate a line as it is in some other part of the code?

For example I want the entire text to remain in a single line as it was before,

```
  case "foo" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
  case "bar" : {DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; DoSomething; break }
```

Comment: are you asking about formatting code layout?

Comment: i thionk the question is - how to preserve format when I paste

Comment: You could disable automatic formatting on paste in Visual Studio's options, but I believe it would apply globally.

Comment: I understand this is a formatting question, but are you familiar with the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#C.23)? There's a much better way of maintaining the code you have.

Comment: you can turn it off glbally in tools>options>text editor> c# > formating. Or use the wonder full ctrlQ + 'paste'

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're experiencing a "feature" of Visual Studio that auto-formats code on certain actions (completed statement on <kbd>;</kbd>, completed block on <kbd>}</kbd>, or on <kbd>Paste</kbd>. Fortunately, these preferences can be changed via the following settings page (they are language-specific):

#### VS 2015

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting`

Then temporarily uncheck the **Automatically format on paste** option.

[image: General C# formatting options]

#### VS 2017/2019

In Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, the "Formatting" options moved underneath a new "Code Style" menu and added some extra settings:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

This might sound silly, but the way the paste and reformat feature works in Visual Studio is that Visual Studio first pastes, *and then* formats the text in various steps.

If you don't want to disable the "Automatically format on paste" feature, try this:

1. Paste the text as normal (VS will format the text, but hang on)
2. Undo (Ctrl + Z) multiple times until all formatting steps have been reverted

Comment: This is the only solution that I found to be **working**. Thank you.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer; this is so much easier than toggling options.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is related to reordering in general this may be helpful as well.

To easy reorder code: select code to move then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to move the selection up or down. For indenting the selection use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move indentation back.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit late but if someone is still having problems with this, try using paste without formatting shortcut(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

It works for me on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: this doesn't work. what it does for me is that it prompts me to choose from text recently copied to the clipboard

Comment: It works in VS2015. This should be the accepted answer, it does not require set options or do things in more steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Assist make sure you also disable the option from `Visual Assist options -> Editor -> Format after paste`, as Visual Assist has its auto auto-format-after-paste feature.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off all auto-formatting prior to paste.